# Java shortcut for consumptionstore

Tags: java, syntax

Is there an already existing java class which could substitute this class that I have made to store raw data?

```
package scripts.util.function;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ConsumptionStore implements Serializable {

/**
 * Holds data
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7390032854804146344L;

private Object[] data;

public ConsumptionStore(Object...data){
    this.data = data;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T get(int index){
    return (T) data[index];
}

public void set(int index, Object value){
    data[index] = value;
}


}
```

It is mostly used to store data like this:

```
OwnedHouses[] houses_I_own;
OwnedVehicles[] vehicles_I_own;
int age;
String name;
new ConsumptionStore(houses_I_own, vehicles_I_own, age, name);
```

Comment: Does a `List<Object>` suffice?

Answer (score 0):

[`Arrays.asList(T... a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) works like your constructor and the returned [`List<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) has methods [`get(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) and [`set(int index, T value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-).

However, storing different types of values in a list or array is not a good idea. You should create a dedicated class with the 4 fields you described.

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private OwnedHouses[] ownedHouses;
    private OwnedVehicles[] ownedVehicles;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why is this unsafe? I am not using this class to store more complex items like I used an example of above, but for things like ConsumptionStore(String, Integer)

Comment: @kay Because you have to remember what value is in what position, then cast the value to the right type. If you do it wrong, you won't know until you execute the code. With a dedicated class, you'd know immediately, because the code wouldn't compile. Also, a dedicated object is more explanatory, since it names the fields. 3 years from now, when you look at your code, would you know what `consumptionStore.get(3)` is supposed to return? Would others know?